# Windows Phone utf8 font error

Tags: windows-phone-7, utf-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an application and I have about 25 languages in utf8 format. I am using normal textblock for displaying like

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding visibility2}" x:Name="translation" Text="{Binding translation}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeTranslation}" Foreground="#FF5D2A07" Margin="12,6,6,0" />
```

All the languages are working fine except for Hindi and Bengali translations and they are showing blocks. These same translations are working fine on iPhone but on WP7 it shows like
[image: Hindi]

I have been trying to fix it but I have had no luck, in fact I tried to use Hindi fonts as well but that didn't work as well. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, why `Times New Roman`? It's very against CLAF (common look and feel) for Windows Phone. Further, I think Times New Roman doesn't have all of the language characters defined. Try it with the standard `Segoe UI` and let us know if that works. If Times New Roman does have Hindi characters on iOS, then that is non-standard. If it does not, then they may automatically recognize it and substitute another unicode font.

Comment: Hi, I tried using `Segoe UI` and `Segoe UI Symbol` but again the same result

Comment: Would you please debug the app and post what is being returned by the `translation` property. You may need to do some work in the codebehind to find out what the actual unicode characters attempting to be displayed are.

Comment: Hi in the translation property I have "अल्लाह के नाम से जो रहमान व रहीम है।" which is exactly what I need

Comment: When adding that directly, it works both with Segoe UI and Times New Roman. Make sure that your function is returning that in a unicode font encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: I am not using any function so how should I do this, I am fetching data from database and assign it to listbox which binds to textblock like 

string strSelect = "Select * from tbl_xyz";
App.List = (Application.Current as App).db.SelectList<Aya>(strSelect);

Listbox.ItemsSource = App.List;

Comment: When you fetch it from the database, that is doing a conversion from binary into an array of encoded characters. You need to find out how the characters are being encoded in the database and possibly do a conversion from that system to a unicode-based system such as UTF-8.

Comment: It's important to note that VisualStudio likely does this automatically for you, which is why you may get the right text when you debug.

Comment: Characters are encoded in UTF-8 format and this is why other 25 languages are working fine but Hindi, Bengali and Malayalam are not

Comment: UTF-8 can handle Hindi just fine. I would try and check the code that parses the content from the database or prepares the content to be written to the database. If UTF8 is not working for you, you can try re-encoding the strings as UTF-16 (which is what .NET uses for strings in memory).